# How to create OneNote Content Type in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: document-library, content-type

I created EXCEL,WORD,PowerPoint Content Type by saving as a Template and place for a document library,but i am unable to save the OneNote as a template.can any one give some suggestions about the OneNote.